# Populate editor with some content of a page with a page template

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, pages, page-template

I have a page template like "page-salespage.php". what i'm trying to do is show default content in tinymice editor when this page template applies to a page. here's how i tried to achieve this, but i have no luck.

```
function my_editor_content( $content ) {

if (is_page_template('page-salespage.php'))
{

$content = "This is some custom content I'm adding to the post editor because I hate re-typing it.";

return $content;
}   

}

add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content' );
```

looking for a solution to achive my requirement.

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Comment: help on this please

Comment: You could create a **[CPT](https://generatewp.com/post-type/)** with an own **[Template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates)** and then use a correct coded function to pre-populate that specific Custom Post Type with the content you wish. *Even pre populating a title/an excerpt/a featured image or category (and more) is all doable after that*.

Answer (score 0):

The `is_page_template()` function will not work in the admin. The second parameter of the `default_content` filter is the $post object. Your best bet is to leverage that to get the stored value for the page template in the post meta information:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'wpse_editor_default_content', 10, 2 );

function wpse_editor_default_content( $content, $post ) {

    if ( 'page-salespage.php' === get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ) ) {
        $content = "If you like this post, then please consider retweeting it or sharing it on Facebook.";
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Note that this will only work if you have already assigned the page template and saved it as a draft or published it, otherwise the meta value will not have been assigned yet.